# Installing Dlib 19.4

Tags: ubuntu, dlib

So I cloned a project from git that used dlib 19.4, it always said that the CMake findboost can't find the boost each time I tried to pip install dlib 19.4. But when I install dlib 19.16 it succeed. My CMake version is 3.5.1 and the boost is 16.4 so what went wrong? I prefer using the same version as the original project if possible to save myself from potential problem, or is it guaranteed to be okay using 19.16 like no deprecated function or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the dlib changelog webpage: http://dlib.net/release_notes.html
They dropped Boost.Python in favor of pybind11 in the release of dlib 19.9. That's why you are able to install dlib 19.16 even if cmake is not finding boost.

Comment: I see, and I also figured out why the cmake can't find the boost. Since my cmake is 3.5 I need to lower the boost version.